# Open an existing android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm not able to open existing project , did research but it brought no result. 
I changed(build.gradle) from 0.5.+ to 1.0.0

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
```

also changed (gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) 1-6 to 2.2.1

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

retunrs same exception:

```
The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I use latest version of android studio, downloaded two days later.

Answer (score 0):

There is doc for upgrade Android Studio to 1.0.0 [Migrating Gradle Projects to version 1.0.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0) .

Basically you need change 'runProguard true' to be 'minifyEnabled true' in your build.gradle file